# Passing string as query argument in javascript/angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I am passing a username to get a record from the database. In my controller I have

```
$scope.team=function(data)
team_factory.getMember.query({}, data.username, function(data){
    $scope.team=data;
});
```

In my factory I have

```
return {
   getMember: $resource('/api/AuthMember/GetMember/userName', {}, {query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}})
}
```

When I run this i get Null back for the response. When I looked in the browser tools factory is passing "userName" as string rather then the value of data.username from controller.  Please let me know how I can pass value of data.username to factory. Thanks

Comment: you are missing an apostrophe in the question.

Comment: I fixed it. That was a typo. Original code is working fine. Just I am not able to pass username to the factory properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way.

```
$scope.team=function(data)

team_factory.getMember.query({username: data.username}, function(data){
    $scope.team=data;
});


return {
   getMember: $resource('/api/AuthMember/GetMember/:userName', {userName:'@username'}, {query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}})
}
```

For information please refer this [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)